# Loading HTML5 video from external server

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

Lets say I want to load an html5 video which is found on a distance server and (obviously) has a address (something like http://www.emuze.co/videos/vid_1.mp4).
Can i actually just put this address as the value of the href property, or do I have to do something special (and what do I have to do)?

Thanks for any replies :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the url of external server as far as copy rights are not violated